# plug in creation

Tags: plug-ins, diy

Any people out there developing their own plug ins for bespoke use?
What tools are you using?

Theres something about just using xcode which is un appealing :P, and although I would prefer to develop on a mac, I really dislike the idea of AU only plugs.

Anything you guys are using that google has fail to pop up?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Max4Live](http://cycling74.com/products/maxforlive/).  Failing this or the options mention above you'll have to learn to software program to really write your own plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

[Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) is a pretty standard cross-platform library, although payware.

[SynthMaker](http://synthmaker.co.uk/) is pretty appealing for VST, if the platform is Windows only.

For a hobbyist with a need to put something cross-platform together simply, Reaktor, [Bidule](http://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/) and especially [Usine](http://www.sensomusic.com/usine/) (when it supports Mac too) are good to go.

Comment: Thanks : ) there seems to be a lot of resources for VST stuff, but not as much for DSP, sadly. 

Comment: @Cam A VST is just a package/framework for DSP, no? For DSP prototyping there's Matlab etc. 

Answer (score 0):

Or learn C++? It's not so hard... :) If you want to do plugins for pro tools, you need to write to avid first, to receive SDK (software development toolkit). VST SDK from steinberg is available for everyone.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news first: if you want to develop RTAS plugins, you're pretty much out of luck. Pro Tools is the only major DAW that doesn't have an open plugin SDK; you have to apply to Avid directly and get approved, which, while free, is very unlikely to happen.

Now the good news: the VST SDK is free and open, and if you're willing to shell out a bit of money for FXPansion's VST to RTAS wrapper, you can use your VSTs in Pro Tools. That's how I'm doing it.

Xcode ist just an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), so if you're on a Mac you'll probably end up using it for your coding no matter what SDK you're programming with.

Lastly, most SDKs I know of are written in C or C++, so make sure to brush up on your programming skills.